# How can you calculate the water pressure in a sealed tank where an air bubble above the water is pressurised using a pump?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water

I'm trying to model a solar shower for a camper van conversion where a 17.5 litre sealed tank containing 15 litres of water heated by radiation is pressurised using a bicycle pump (valve on top of the water tank).

Bike pumps reach about 100 psi when pressurising air, but how would pressurising the air impact the water pressure below and how could you work out the water pressure you can achieve?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the tank is not sealed, the pressure from the air on the water is 1 atm.

For a sealed tank with 100 psi of air pressure, this means about 7 atm.